# De HttpUrlConnection a HttpsUrlConnection

Tags: android, http, https

Estuve programando un código (el cual funciona sin ningún inconveniente) que envía todo por HttpUrlConnection. Es el siguiente:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... url){
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url[0]).openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            //Si quiero enviar/recibir una respuesta en el cuerpo del mensaje, tiene que estar lo siguiente:
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream output=new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.write(body.getBytes());
            output.flush();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            String responseString = result.toString();
            inputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            return responseString;

        } catch(Exception exc) {
            String error = exc.toString();
            return error;
        }
    }
```

El problema es que estoy haciendo una aplicación, la cual debería enviar las cosas por `https`. Sin embargo, tengo entendido que en lugar de tener que usar HttpsUrlConnection puedo conservar la clase que estoy usando...Puede ser eso? Hay mucha diferencia entre uno y el otro?

Comment: el código sigue estando bien, solo define tu nueva url aca: url[0]

Comment: Ah, perfecto. No sabía si tendría que romper todo lo que tenía hecho jajajaj. Muchisimas gracias :)